# How to interpret "only" in sentences?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence-meaning

I have hard time understanding how to interpret "only" in sentences. Consider the following statements:

1. "Only on Saturdays I play football".

Can I interpret this as "If I play football then it is Saturday"?

2. "The only friend that might come to my party is John". Does this mean that John is my only friend with 0<P(come to my party)<1 (where P=Probability)? But this does not imply that my other friends will come/not come to my party. Is this correct? Or should I interpret it as "all of my friends won't come to the party except John who may come"?

Comment: It's not ***in*** *Saturdays*, but ***on*** *Saturdays*. (I'm not certain if ***at*** *Saturdays* is acceptable in UK English, as it is with ***at*** *the weekend*, but I'm sure that ***in*** *Saturdays* is not.) And the structure is a little odd. Normally it would be *I only play football on Saturdays*. That aside, your interpretation is correct. But this seems more like an exercise in logic than grammar per se.

Comment: (The second sentence is actually ungrammatical. Replace *maybe* with *might*. I also find the later analysis confusing.)

Comment: The answer to your first question is YES. The answer to your second question is YES. The answer to your third question is NO -- it does imply that none of your other friends will come to the party. The answer to your fourth question is YES.

Comment: The first example sounds like part of a statement to me. The full statement being "I do an hour's circuit training most days, only on Saturdays I play football" which implies that the speaker doesn't train on Saturdays but plays football instead. If I were to say that I didn't play football on any other day of the week I'd say "I only play football on Saturdays" or, more formally, "I play football only on Saturdays". However both of these forms are ambiguous and can be taken to mean "I do nothing on Saturdays but play football". Starting a sentence with "only" does not sound natural to me.

Comment: Search for “only” in the search box. Many questions about this word have been answered.

Comment: @RichardKayser How can we conclude that my other friend won't come?

Comment: We can conclude that your other friend/friends won't come because you've said John is your only friend who might come. You are saying at the same time that there is zero chance any of your other friends will come. That said, I'll risk confusing matters with a different interpretation in case that's what you're really asking about. If John is your only friend who *might* come, maybe you are saying that you know all you other friends *will* come, that your only question regarding attendees is John. I didn't consider that possibility at first because of your example of football only on Saturdays.